How to find IEnumerable<T>.ToList() method by explicitly specifying type of parameters and then call it with a custom parameter type?
Let's say we have the following code (highly simplified modification of my own code):
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ReflectionTest
{
    public interface IDataContext
    { }

    sealed class DataContext : IDataContext
    { }

    public interface ITable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
        where T : class
    {
        List<T> source { get; }
    }


    sealed class Table<T> : ITable<T>
        where T : class, new()
    {
        public Table()
        {
            source = new List<T>() { new T() };
        }

        public List<T> source { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => source.GetEnumerator();

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => source.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public static class DataExtensions
    {
        public static ITable<T> GetTable<T>(this IDataContext dataContext)
            where T : class, new()
        {
            return new Table<T>();
        }
    }

    public class TestData
    {
        public string Name = "Test";
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dataContext = new DataContext();

            //var ret = dataContext.GetTable<TestData>().ToList(); but via reflection:
            var getTableMethod = typeof(DataExtensions).GetMethod("GetTable", new[] { typeof(IDataContext) });
            var getTableGeneric = getTableMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TestData));
            var testDataITable = getTableGeneric.Invoke(null, new object[] { dataContext });

            //var toListMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList", new[] { typeof(IEnumerable) });   this doesn't find IEnumerable<T>.ToList() method!
            var toListMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList");
            var toListGeneriс = toListMethod.MakeGenericMethod(testDataITable.GetType());

            //System.ArgumentException: 'Unable to cast object of type "ReflectionTest.Table`1[ReflectionTest.TestData]"
            //to type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ReflectionTest.Table`1[ReflectionTest.TestData]]".'
            var ret = toListGeneriс.Invoke(null, new object[] { testDataITable });

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

I'm trying to call var ret = dataContext.GetTable<TestData>().ToList(); but via reflection. And I have two problems here:

typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList", new[] { typeof(IEnumerable) }); doesn't find IEnumerable.ToList() method. I know that there is only one version of this method and I can simply use typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList"); - but still, how to find it by explicitly specifying type of parameters?
How can I then correctly call this method with ITable<TestData> parameter type? With my code I get an exception:


System.ArgumentException: 'Unable to cast object of type
"ReflectionTest.Table`1[ReflectionTest.TestData]" to type
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ReflectionTest.Table`1[ReflectionTest.TestData]]


It's entirely possible that what I say is not relevant to your real use case because the example is too simplified, but in general you don't need to get ToList by reflection: Generics are mainly a compile-time tool. There's (usually, exceptions apply) no need to use generics in dynamically-typed code.

@Heinzi My real code is much more complicated and I definitelly need to use reflection.

Looks like for linq2db. Can you explain in detail what is expected? Everything can be made simplier.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Wow, incredible guess! That is really for linq2db.
I have Sql Ce database (49 tables) and I need to copy all data to same SQLite database. And instead of calling
var existingData1= dataContextSqlCe.GetTable<MyType1>().ToList(); dataContextSQLite.BulkCopy(existingData1); 49 times I decided to use reflection.
I get table types via var tableTypes = dataContextSqlCe.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => typeof(ITable<>).IsSameOrParentOf(p.PropertyType)).Select(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]) and iterate.
P. S. Thank you for the great library.

Well, it is doaeble, but what you plan to do with tables insert order? Or it does not matter?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Tables insert order doesn't matter in this particular case. But most likely it will be important in our next project. There we plan to hardcode a Dictionary<TableName, InsertOrder> and apply .OrderBy() to a tableTypes obtaining code above. Do you see any optimizations in this two cases?

Nothing special here, just sort tables/types.

Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

For the first problem, you can use Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter to create a "type parameter".

Returns a signature type object that can be passed into the Type[] array parameter of a GetMethod method to represent a generic parameter reference.

Then use that to create a Type representing IEnumerable<TSource>. Passing that to GetMethod will gets you the desired method.
var typeVariable = Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0);
var parameterType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeVariable)
var toListMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList", [parameterType]);

For the second problem, it is because you parameterised ToList incorrectly. Recall the signature of ToList:
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource> (
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source
);

TSource should be the element type of the collection - TestData, not the type of the collection itself.
var toListGeneriс = toListMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TestData));


Thank you. But Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter is available only since in .Net Core 2.1 (or .Net Standard 2.1). What code should I use on .Net Framework 4.7.2 (or .Net Standard 2.0)?

@bairog Well then you have to do something ugly like this, I think.

I've also found similar answer. Thank you, it's ugly but working.

For linq2db there are helper methods which helps to wotk with reflections. But if your goal is to copy database to another database, there is simplier option.
public static class BulkCopyExtensions
{
    public static void CopyData<T>(this IQueryable<T> sourceQuery, IDataContext destination) where T : class
    {
        destination.GetTable<T>().BulkCopy(sourceQuery.AsEnumerable());
    }

    public static void CopyData<T>(this IDataContext source, IDataContext destination) where T : class
    {
        CopyData(source.GetTable<T>(), destination);
    }

    // MemberHelper.MethodOfGeneric is linq2db method
    private static readonly MethodInfo _copyDataConnections = MemberHelper.MethodOfGeneric(() => ((DataConnection)null!).CopyData<object>(null!));

    public static void CopyAllData(this IDataContext source, IDataContext destination) 
    {
        var typesForCopy = source.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(p => typeof(ITable<>).IsSameOrParentOf(p.PropertyType))
            .Select(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0])
            .ToList();

        foreach (var type in typesForCopy)
        {
            _copyDataConnections.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null, [source, destination]);
        }
    }
}

So, in your case, copying databse is just call CopyAllData extension method.
dataContextSqlCe.CopyAllData(dataContextSqLite);

Note that this method do not care about order of inserts an you many have FK errors.

Thank you. I will use that handy helper methods.
